# Can javascript Math.random() really reach 0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

Based on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) Math.random() can return **0** but can not return **1**

> The Math.random() static method returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number that's **greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1**

I tried to loop Math.random() to get 10 number below **e-10** and it takes **15 minutes** to complete it with my 4 cores 8 threads cpu and from that 10 numbers **0 never get returned**. Is my test case just too small or latest javascript Math.random() can never return 0?

*note: I run the code using **node.js v18.12.1** and the smallest number ever returned is **5.2724491439448684e-12** (yes its small, but it isn't 0)*

```
let countSmallNumber = 0;
let temp = 0;
console.time("loopTime");
while (countSmallNumber < 10) {
    temp = Math.random();
    if (temp < 0.0000000001) {
        countSmallNumber++;
        console.log(`almost 0 => ${temp}`);
    }
}
console.timeEnd("loopTime");
```

Comment: It can return 0, but the probability of returning any specific number is just extremely low. You might also find, for example, that it never returned `0.54`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Well, technically, there is no such thing as `0.54` in floats, so `0` is even easier to find.

Comment: [Something interesting to read.](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random)

Comment: @chrslg My gut told me the same thing, but went away to research and came back to see your comment.

Comment: @spender Well, it is quite easy to predict: if it is not an integer, and doesn't end with a 5, then, there aren't any float representation of it (sufficient condition, not necessary, for not being a float. For example, 0.135 is a non integer ending with a 5, and yet, it is not a float neither. But that sufficient condition was sufficient to tell in a split second that 0.54 can't be a float).

Comment: Of course, one may point out that probability of `Math.random()==0.54` is still the same as `Math.random()==0`, since `Math.random()==0.54` doesn't really compare to 0.54, since that litteral 0.54 is parsed as the closest float, so what it does in reality is compare `Math.random()` to `0.54000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`. But well, if you really compare `Math.random()` to `0.54` (for example using a decimal library) answer to "how often it happens" has to be "never".

Comment: But of course, I am just playing a bit here. @Unmitigated comment remains the correct answer. 0 is as likely as any other existing float, including  `0.54000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`, which is what `0.54` means.